# Oracle DB problem using Kafka Sink Connector

Tags: java, oracle, apache-kafka

I'm new to the sink connector. When I use the sink connector to receive data, I get the following error.

```
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-01400/
Error : 1400, Position : 0, SQL = INSERT INTO "RENTED_PRODUCT"("PRODUCT_NO","RENT_START_DATE","RENT_END_DATE","OWNER_NICKNAME","BORROWER_NICKNAME","STATUS","REVIEW_STATUS") VALUES(:1 ,:2 ,:3 ,:4 ,:5 ,:6 ,:7 ), Original SQL = INSERT INTO "RENTED_PRODUCT"("PRODUCT_NO","RENT_START_DATE","RENT_END_DATE","OWNER_NICKNAME","BORROWER_NICKNAME","STATUS","REVIEW_STATUS") VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?), Error Message = ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TEST1"."RENTED_PRODUCT"."RENTED_PRODUCT_NO")


        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:165)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:111)
        ... 12 more
[2023-12-07 10:20:17,979] ERROR [rentedproduct2-sink-connect|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=rentedproduct2-sink-connect-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:212)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:336)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:237)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The connector has the following configuration

```
{
    "name": "rentedproduct2-sink-connect",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "RENTED_PRODUCT",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe",
        "connection.user": "test1",
        "connection.password": "test1",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "pk.mode": "none",
        "auto.create": "false",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true"
    }
}
```

RENTED_PRODUCT_NO corresponding to PK does not exist in schema and payload

The data format sent to the topic is as follows

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "int64",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "PRODUCT_NO"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "RENT_START_DATE"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "RENT_END_DATE"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "OWNER_NICKNAME"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "BORROWER_NICKNAME"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "STATUS"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "REVIEW_STATUS"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "RENTED_PRODUCT"
    },
    "payload": {
        "product_no": 1,
        "rent_start_date": "2023-12-12 11:00",
        "rent_end_date": "2023-12-15 12:00",
        "owner_nickname": "Owener",
        "borrower_nickname": "Borrower",
        "status": "Using",
        "review_status": "None"
    }
}
```

Please help me. I haven't been able to find a cause for a day :(

Creating a table using JPA,

```
create table rented_product 
(rented_product_no number(19,0) not null, 
borrower_nickname varchar2(255 char) not null, 
owner_nickname varchar2(255 char) not null, 
product_no number(19,0) not null, 
rent_end_date timestamp not null, 
rent_start_date timestamp not null, 
review_status varchar2(255 char), 
status varchar2(255 char), 
primary key (rented_product_no))
```

part of the entity

```
     @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "SEQ_GENERATOR",
            sequenceName = "RENTEDPRODUCT_SEQ",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private Long rentedProductNo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long productNo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", timezone = "Asia/Seoul")
    private LocalDateTime rentStartDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", timezone = "Asia/Seoul")
    private LocalDateTime rentEndDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String ownerNickname;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String borrowerNickname;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ReviewStatus reviewStatus;
```

It went well when I did it with MySQL, But as we proceed to Oracle, PK using sequence keeps going into Null

Comment: Please include the DDL for the table, its constraints, and explain how you are using the sequence to generate the ID value.

Comment: @pmdba I modified the text

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you are using is:

```sql
INSERT INTO "RENTED_PRODUCT"("PRODUCT_NO","RENT_START_DATE","RENT_END_DATE","OWNER_NICKNAME","BORROWER_NICKNAME","STATUS","REVIEW_STATUS") VALUES(:1 ,:2 ,:3 ,:4 ,:5 ,:6 ,:7 )
```

The error you get is:

```sql
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TEST1"."RENTED_PRODUCT"."RENTED_PRODUCT_NO")
```

This is because you have not included `RENTED_PRODUCT_NO` in the columns you are inserting so the default value for that column is used, which appears to be `NULL`.

You state that the entity contains:

```sql
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
  name = "SEQ_GENERATOR",
  sequenceName = "RENTEDPRODUCT_SEQ",
  allocationSize = 1
)
```

In that case, the query (assuming that you are providing it manually) should include the primary key column:

```sql
INSERT INTO "RENTED_PRODUCT (
  "RENTED_PRODUCT_NO",
  "PRODUCT_NO",
  "RENT_START_DATE",
  "RENT_END_DATE",
  "OWNER_NICKNAME",
  "BORROWER_NICKNAME",
  "STATUS",
  "REVIEW_STATUS"
) VALUES(
  "RENTEDPRODUCT_SEQ".NEXTVAL,
  :1,
  :2,
  :3,
  :4,
  :5,
  :6,
  :7
)
```

Alternatively, from Oracle 12, you can use an `IDENTITY` column in the DDL for your table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE rented_product (
  rented_product_no number(19,0)
                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                    not null, 
  borrower_nickname varchar2(255 char) not null, 
  owner_nickname    varchar2(255 char) not null, 
  product_no        number(19,0) not null, 
  rent_end_date     timestamp not null, 
  rent_start_date   timestamp not null, 
  review_status     varchar2(255 char), 
  status            varchar2(255 char), 
  primary key (rented_product_no)
)
```

Then your query should work.